# Can we derive equation for horizontal range of projectile from 3rd equation of motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I used the equation v² - u² = 2as and came up with the the following result. But on verifying it for theta = 45 it fails. Where am I wrong?[image]

Comment: Horizontal acceleration is not $g$! It's zero under ideal circumstances. So the first equation and hence the entire derivation is wrong.

Comment: And the final velocity $v$ for horizontal motion is not zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have taken the final velocity (horizontal component) to be $0$, which is wrong and also the acceleration isn't $g$ rather it is $0$ as you've considered horizontal motion only.

When we talk about 2-dimensional motion, the horizontal velocity of the object is unaffected by the acceleration due to gravity as the acceleration vector and horizontal velocity vector are perpendicular to each other. This is why the acceleration due to gravity only affects the vertical velocity and not the horizontal velocity.

Now, if the acceleration due to gravity doesn't affect the horizontal component of velocity and the only acceleration possible in this scenario is given to be the acceleration due to gravity, then there is no acceleration in the horizontal direction. The magnitude of the horizonal velocity vector must not change, therefore implying that the final velocity of the horizontal component of velocity cannot be zero as the initial horizontal velocity is non-zero.

In a nutshell, if we consider the horizontal components, the initial and final velocity $u$ and $v$ are the same as acceleration due to gravity doesn't affect the horizontal component of the velocity vector. Therefore, $v \not\neq 0$ and $u=v$. Therefore, $v^2 - u^2 = 2as$ just gives us $0=0$ as $a=0 \not\neq g$.